# Next.js 14, getting CORS Error on login request, using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on admin-panel, using latest next.js 14, with typescript.
I have simple post request for admin login,(with axios, react-hook-form), but I get CORS error.

**"has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."**

For the backend, php is used and testing login **through the  postman is working. **

I don't know where  the problem. Because backend developer tells me, that it is working with postman and should not happen any error.
Might be any issue with next.js 14 itself?

I tried then to send data with FormData and was successful for a while, but now I still have the same issue, CORS Error.

```
import axios from "axios";

export const AdminLogin = async (params: any) => {

  try {
    
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `${URL}`,
      params
    );
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const onSubmit = async () => {
    const emailInput = document.getElementById("email") as HTMLInputElement;
    const passwordInput = document.getElementById(
      "password"
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
  
    const formData = new FormData();
  
    formData.append("email", emailInput.value);
    formData.append("password", passwordInput.value);
  
    try {
      const response = await AdminLogin(formData);
      
      if (response && response.token) {
        Cookies.set("authToken", response.token); 
        router.push("/main");
      } else {
        console.error("Token not found in the response");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login:", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `working with postman` doesn't mean anything when you have cross origin requests - postman isn't a browser - server needs to send CORS response headers if the server wants to allow cross origin resource sharing